# Setting Up Multi-Server Administration---SQL Server Account

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am trying to set up Multi Server Administration so that I can easily update multiple instances of the same database across our network with ease. Where I am getting lost is how to set up the `SQL SERVER AGENT` service on the target machines.

Right now the SQL SERVER AGENT services on the machines are set to log on as `NTSERVICE\SQL SERVER AGENT`.

My SQL Server Agent process is set to log in as `LocalSystem`

My overall goal here is to figure out why I can't set any target servers from my machine, as I always run into the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
------------------------------

MSX enlist failed for JobServer 'MYPC'. 

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18206.0+((SSMS_Rel).191029-2112)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=MSX+enlist+JobServer&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The enlist operation failed (reason: SQLServerAgent Error: Unable to connect to MSX 'MYPC'.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22026)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.2027&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=22026&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

When looking at the log on my machine I see the following error when trying to enlist the target machine:

`Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One weakness of MSX is that target servers uses Windows authentication and you can't change that.

I.e., your target Agent need a domain account as a service account and that account need to exist as a Windows login on the master SQL Server (and also be a user in the msdb database there and a member of the TargetServersRole).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have to also add users logins into the "SSISDB"?

Comment: Ssisdb has nothing to do with MSX, so it isn't needed for MSX.